# Windows не видит SSL сертификаты

Tags: windows, cmd, ssl, powershell

Запускаю код на Python ниже в терминале:

google = "https://google.com"
a = requests.get(google)

Получаю

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
httplib_response = self._make_request(
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
self._validate_conn(conn)
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
conn.connect()
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 416, in connect
self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
return self.sslsocket_class._create(
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
self.do_handshake()
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 440, in send
resp = conn.urlopen(
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
retries = retries.increment(
File "C:\MyPC\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 592, in increment
raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
```

Проблема явно с SSL сертификатом, данная проблема возникает при доступе к любому сайту.
Пробую также heroku update (обновление CLI для сервиса Heroku)

```
heroku: Updating CLI... !
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
```

Проблема та же. Видимо, что-то не так с настройкой Windows. Подскажите, в чем проблема? Сижу в обычной сети, поменять пробовал.

Скриншот сертификата google.com из Google Chrome
[image: Скриншот сертификата google.com из Google Chrome]

Comment: А в браузере открывается? Покажите скриншот с информацией о сертификате google.com из браузера

Comment: Добавил скрин в вопрос. В браузере всё открывается. Более того, иногда удается нормально отработать python скрипту, то есть ошибки не вылетает и приходит ответ 200. А вот с хероку ещё ни разу нормально не отработало

Comment: «InfoWatch Transparency Proxy Root» — на вашем компьютере проведена MitM-атака, и весь ваш трафик прослушивается кем-то посторонним. Именно поэтому программы, которые выполняют проверку сертификата, предупреждают о проблеме безопасности. Это правильное поведение. Чтобы решить проблему, вам нужно устранить последствия MitM-атаки на компьютер

Comment: Это рабочий ноутбук - может поэтому кто-то по середине?

Comment: В таком случае, наверное, спрашивайте у вашей работы, что с этим делать

Comment: А отключение SSL в приложениях, которые я использую, решит проблему, не знаете?

Comment: Вы не сможете отключить SSL в приложениях, потому что серверы требуют обязательное его использование

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за помощь. Если напишите ответ, то отмечу решением

Comment: Я не знаю конкретных подробностей, что там у вас происходит с вашей MitM-атакой (спрашивайте на работе), но в общем случае обычно нужно добавить «посторонний» сертификат в хранилище доверенных сертификатов в настройках Windows, как-то так https://zawindows.ru/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8/

Comment: Аа, да, такие сертификаты есть у меня на работе. А их установка решит проблему с сертификатами? Мне казалось, что они нужны только для доступа к ресурсам компании, а не ко всем сайтам с устройства

Comment: Если ваша компания решила перехватывать трафик всех сайтов, то придётся устанавливать сертификат для доступа ко всем сайтам ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Понял, благодарю